# ConcurrentHashMap: a non-obvious return from the addCount() method

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

In the everybody's favorite `ConcurrentHashMap` class, we observe the following non-obvious return from the `addCount()` method (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/15481041e0636291cc3516a48c9250d77ded2594/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L2335):

```
 fullAddCount(x, uncontended);
 return;
```

However, this appears to contradict the method's intent stated in the docs, that is:

> Adds to count, and if table is too small and not already resizing, initiates transfer.

This particular return appears to had been there from the very beginning, which begs the question: is this some sort of cunning performance optimization or merely an omission, undetected in years?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why you think the return at this place violates the mentioned contract? Perhaps add your understanding of which situation this branch handles, and which part is (not) covered by what `fullAddCount` does.

Comment: This is quite obvious from the structure of that (short) method.

Comment: What I mean is, if I am not mistaken, this is the branch dealing with the "already resizing" case, correct? I is entered if setting the counter cell is contested.

Comment: `fullAddCount` follows the general structure of `longAccumulate` and has nothing to do with table copying/resizing. Thus, we only have the block in `addCount` which is not reachable when this particular branch is taken.

Comment: Perhaps someone with a deeper understanding of this function can shed some light on what this branch handles, exactly. I've tried to think about ways to enter this branch that would lead to an observable bug, but have been unable to come up with any.

Comment: Thus the question. :-)